# updating tabitem datatemplate when changing selected tab

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an object(MyCals) that is type of Cal Collection. (Cal is an object).

The MyCals consists of 2 Cal, where each Cal has List of Events (Events does not has the INotifyPropertyChanged interface implemented, it has many properties like Summary, Id,...)

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCals, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!--  Tab Header -->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ProductID}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

                <!--  Content  -->
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                       <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                                  HorizontalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Events, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Summary}" Header="Summary" />
                                                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            </TabControl>
```

Now the TabControl will show 2 tabs with the right header, but the Datagrid wont update when I change select the other tab. So if the First Tab is selected, that datagrid will be showed with the Data from first Cal, but when I select the second tab, data in the datagrid are not getting updated 
(Same Events in the MyCals[1])

any help is really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you implemented the ViewModel so I did a quick test and it works.

This is the code of the ViewModel:

```
class MainViewModel : AbstractViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.MyCals = new ObservableCollection<Cal>();
        this.MyCals.Add(new Cal());
        this.MyCals.Add(new Cal());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Cal> MyCals { get; set; }
}

public class Cal
{
    public Cal()
    {
        this.ProductID = "Product " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        this.Events = new ObservableCollection<Event>();
        this.Events.Add(new Event());
        this.Events.Add(new Event());
    }

    public string ProductID { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        this.Summary = "Event Summary " + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

Please share a bit more about the code behind if my sample didn't help.